# Creating clients of SQL Server 2008 in same network

Tags: sql-server-2008

My application contains a SQL Server 2008 and I have to install that application on 10 computers which are in the same network.

All applications should connect to the same SQL Server 2008 database

I am installing SQL Server 2008 on one of the machines, but is it necessary to install it on every machine in the network?

Or is there any shortcut to access to database (which is in network) without installation on every single machine.

Comment: If you have a connection string in your application's config, you can put there the IP or name of the machine where you have installed SQL Server 2008. You must configure SQL Server 2008 to allow remote connections ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 64bit.
Sql server 2008 R2
SQL server mangement studio 2008

First install Sql server 2008 r2
Restart PC
Install SQL Server management studio 2008 as seprate instance.

For network Configuration

1-Turn Off Windows Firewall
2- Make sure That the Browser service is running and set to automatic.
3- in sqlserver confuguration manager go to sqlservernetworkconfiguration > Protocls for network

Enable TCP/IP.

You are done. :)